# The meaning of 飲み友か或いはもっとより良い関係を結べるか

Tags: translation

> 飲み友か或いはもっとより良い関係を結べるか

That sentence is difficult. This is my interpretation:

> I wonder if being drinking friends is better or if it's better to have
>   another (better) kind of relationship ...

Am I off the mark? If so, what's the real meaning?

Comment: (Was あるいは spelt with kanji in the original?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 「飲{の}み友{とも}か或{ある}いはもっとより良{よ}い関係{かんけい}を結{むす}べるか」

It is difficult to translate this phrase accurately without further context because grammatically speaking, a few words are left unsaid.  That is why I chose to use the word "phrase" rather than "sentence".

What we know for certain is that someone is trying to choose between **two options**.

Option A: 飲み友の関係のままでいる "continuing to stay as drinking pals"

Option B: もっと良い関係を結ぶ "building a better and/or more meaningful relationship (than above)"

Again, for the lack of context, one could not tell if the speaker is talking to himself or talking to another person.  That is something only you would  know.